# regex operators

Tags: php, regex

I can detect a file has extension `.php` using the following regular expression:

```
$object = new RegexIterator(
    $iterator,
    '/^.+\.php$/i',
    RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH
);
```

Now I want to extend it to detect if a file has extension `.php` or `.phtml`. How can I do that? Maybe have some operators?

Comment: I've never used `RegexIterator` but i'd assume `/^.+\.ph(?:p|tml)$` would do it. That says the string can end with `.php` or `.phtml`.

Comment: [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Answer (score 0):

`/^.+\.(?:php|phtml)$/i`

Using the `|` operator, the regex will match anything before or after it. So in this case, within that group, either "php" or "phtml" will be matched.

@Marc B linked to a fuller explanation of how this works.